# How do you combine/merge two resultsets using mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

How do I get a **single** resultset for a `Student` that also includes the classroom information - `description` and the `name` of the student? Is this possible?

`Classroom` has a 1-to-N relationship with `Student` in my current example

`Classrooms.first` currently returns

```
Classroom {
  :_id => "5222da075d39f3e4e802000a",
  :description => "Learn english",
  :student_id => "50f9d5bc5d39f30ebb010004"
}
```

`Classroom.first.student.first` currently only returns:

```
Student {
  :_id => "50f9d5bc5d39f30ebb010004",
  :name => "Michael",
  :classroom_id => "5222da075d39f3e4e802000a"
}
```

Comment: you can always override the inspect method of mongoid document, but a work around can be: `student.first.as_json(methods: ['classroom'])`. It will give you a hash with classroom info included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is one solution:-

```
Classroom.first.attributes.merge(Classroom.first.student.first.attributes)
```

It will return a hash with both the model values